# In which table in database Magento 2 product will insert with image and custom attribute?

Tags: magento2, product, database, table

What are the basic tables which need to use, so Product data will be inserted with image and custom attribute.

Which is visible both in frontend and admin.

Please Any one point out the table name for the products entry.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product image paths are stored in '**catalog_product_entity_varchar**'  table in Magento 2.

Below you can see attribute_id field which holds the meaning of each value, for example, attribute_id with values **87, 88, 89 are the attributes for the image**.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

---

**Additionally if you wish to figure out how you can store product's images programmatically, you may find this article useful** : https://magemeta.com/2020/03/31/magento-2-add-image-to-product-programmatically/

Comment: Thanks for your response @Natha
what about custom attribute and product info.

Comment: entity_id you see in the table is product id the image or attribute is associated with.

Comment: Yupp got that bit i want to know about all tables that stores the data of product @Natha

Comment: In question you asked related to images of product, please be specific. Anyway, you can find tables related to product starting with prefix as “catalog_product_”.

Comment: Ah, sorry for that i want to know about all the tables where product data is stored and thought asked the same question.
'catalog_product_' prefix has 74 tables so all the tables would be used @Natha

Comment: Yes, Magento uses all those tables to store values based on attribute codes and based on it’s type.

Comment: okk thanks for the info @Natha

Comment: You’re welcome :)

Comment: I have saved my value in 87, 88, 89 these attribute but it doesn't show image in magento 2 front end nor in backend it shows on search page but not in single page.@Natha will u please help